# Set a Windows Line input device as a Microphone input device?

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, sound-card, rosetta-stone

I am attempting to use Rosetta Stone (Windows 8.1).  My microphone config is an XLR microphone connected to a Focusrite Scarlett 2i4 USB Audio interface.  This equipment works fine for any other application requiring a microphone. It shows up in the Windows Sound settings under the Recording section as "Line In", but the fine people down at Rosetta Stone decided to program their application in such a way that you can *only* use **microphone** inputs and it won't let you select a line input.  My input is a line input...

I had been using a rig with [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) and [Voicemeeter](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/banana.htm) that allowed me to run my microphone through Voicemeeter and out into a Virtual Audio Cable which I configured to be labeled as a **microphone** input.  This worked wonderfully, but unfortunately I had to switch from Virtual Audio Cable to [VB-Cable](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/) because it caused instability on my system (occasional BSODs).  Unfortunately, VB-Cable does not allow you to set its output as a microphone line.

So here I am... is it possible to reassign a line device as a microphone device? I couldn't find a reference to this situation across a plethora of searches.

Answer (score 0):

if using Voicemeeter, why not connecting your application to Voicemeeter output which is a recording device (like microphone input). You normally don't need additional cable to do that... follow user manual until step 5 (replace Skype by your application): http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/Voicemeeter_UserManual.pdf

Comment: This would work but unfortunately, Rosetta Stone does not recognize the Voicemeeter outputs as "Microphones".  This is an issue where it ONLY will let you choose devices specifically marked as a Microphone (headsets, webcam mics, etc).  The Focusrite Scarlett is not marked as such, nor are the Voicemeeter Outputs.

Comment: ha, very strange, did you try to set Voicemeeter Recording device as your default recording device ? as communication device ?

Comment: Yes I have had it that way for a while.  It still does not let you select it

Comment: ok, Should contact people from Rosetta-Stone to ask them why and how they implement this limitation....if there is a workaround or update that corrects this problem...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I literally just did this with a focusrite 6i6 2nd gen.
Windows10
Focusrite Control 3.5
I have a 1/4" - 3.5mm cable connected from one of the line outs into my PCs Mic in jack. Mine happens to be red. The problem OP previously discussed occurred when I plugged it in to the blue Line In port.

[FocusriteControl Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AdqA.png)
[Sound Settings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6ZGm.png)

Comment: I can’t tell — are you saying that you had the same problem and you fixed it, or that you *have* the same problem (period)?